# Display React component Source code using <code> tag

Tags: reactjs, components

I am creating a react styleguide. I am not using any markdown.I want to display component, description, source code of the component. I can display them using code tag if I keep the entire source code in a variable and display them. (see below)

```
 render() {
   var text = `<h1>Helllooo</h1>`;
    return (
     <div>
       <pre>
         <code>
           {text}
         </code>
       </pre>
     </div>
   );
 }
```

But is there any way I can get the source code using a url and display inside code tag
for example get the code from components/Button/index.js and display it inside code tag ? Please help!

Comment: If I understand your question, it's no. The component is the function, react child can't be function.

Comment: So how can i display the source code of any component next to it in my styleguide? any idea?

Comment: You could try some convert jsx to string library, but in case you want to show the whole code of that component, it seems too complex to do that (or impossible). I prefer to use `markdown` to document.

Comment: Try using this package react-syntax-highlighter from npm, it does that, Just load/fetch your code string and display using the guid from the package documantaion.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few libraries that might help you with what you want to do. Try searching for 'jsx to string'.

I've personally used [react-element-to-jsx-string](https://github.com/algolia/react-element-to-jsx-string) and it worked pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

What you are essentially trying to do here is to render HTML markup using React. Your markup can still be in string format, but ideally, they should be received via props and not be hardcoded in a component.

React by default offers `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as a way to accomplish this. But that is not recommended due to security reasons - https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

As Grandas suggested, try using a library or a plugin to do the same. `html-react-parser` is one alternative I could think of - https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser

Answer (score -2):

You can try storing it in array instead of Sting

You can visit https://jsfiddle.net/rajatdhoot/ara1mdam/1/
to run the code

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
 render() {
  var text = [<h2>Hello</h2>]
   return text
  }
 }
 ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
 );
```

Html Code

```
<div id="container">
</div>
```